# Variance and covariance

Tags: statistics, covariance

I'm practicing for an exam and a mock question has me completely stumped. If someone could show me the steps I would be very grateful!

There are two random variables, $A$ and $B$. $Var(A) = 9$, and $Var(B) = 4$, and $Cov(A, B) = 2$.

**a)** What is $Var(2A - 3B + 10)$?

**b)** $U = A + B$, and $V = A + aB$, where $a$ is decided so $Cov(U, V) = 0$. What are the possible values of $a$?

**c)** $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously distributed with the Normal distribution, where $U$ and $V$ are the same as in the previous problem. What is $Cov(e^{sU}, e^{rV})$?

Comment: For a) you can use the formula for the variance of a sum: $Var(aX + bY + c) = a^2Var(X) + b^2Var(Y) -2ab Cov(X,Y)$

Comment: @JonathanHahn, you mean $+$, I think

Comment: Yes, I mean $+$. I can't edit a comment I guess. I'm new, what's the etiquette here? Delete and rewrite or just leave it?

Comment: If I understood this correctly, would it be 2^2*9 + 3^2*4 + 2*2*3*2 despite the minus sign in question a? Is this because it's an absolute sum?

Comment: Yes, your answer is right, I just put a minus sign where there should be a plus sign in the formula. My bad.

Comment: For b) you can use covariance properties: $Cov(X + Y, Z) = Cov(X, Z) + Cov(Y,Z)$ and $Cov(aX,Y) = a Cov(X,Y)$. I think I got these ones right.

Comment: c) seems to depend on the mean of U and V (which depend on the mean of A and B -- are they supposed to have mean 0?). The [section on multivariate log-normal distributions on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Multivariate_log-normal) has a formula for the covariance matrix.

Comment: Bit unsure if the formula covers question b)...

Comment: You can swap the arguments of Cov and you have the same formula, and $Cov(X,X) = Var(X)$. So you get $Cov(U,V) = Cov(A+B, A + aB)$ $= Cov(A, A + aB) + Cov(B, A + aB)$ $= Cov(A, A) + Cov(A, aB) + Cov(B, A) + Cov(B, aB)$ $= Var(A) + a Cov(A, B) + Cov(A,B) + a Var(B)$. Does that help?